# What options are there to minimize thread corrosion in rust-prone applications?

Tags: rust, diy

Any carbon steel thread that suffers from prolonged exposure to air, moisture and (sometimes) salt will suffer from rust, sometimes to the point where [it creates problems](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/27319/675).

While many fixes exist to remove a seized nut or bolt, I want to know if there are smarter fixes out there to *prevent* or at least *minimize* corrosion.

Engineering theory will suggest the following generic strategies:

- ***physical prevention***

  like applying coatings that don't let moisture reach the steel itself
- ***chemical inhibition***

  like sacrificial protection through zinc coatings
- ***change of material***

  like using a brass instead of steel

---

So, to reiterate my question:

***What rust-inhibition strategies exist that are accessible to the average automotive DIY-er?***

Comment: Are you talking about just fixtures, or any rust prone metal (ie: body or suspension parts)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one that comes to mind is anti-seize compound. Some are a mix of aluminum, copper, and graphite lubricant. I use this all the time on my lugs nuts (2000 Toyota Camry with steel wheels) and it seems to keep the rust monster from seizing the threads.

Comment: I use anti-seize with just about everything.  Really helps.  My uncle used it when assembling the exhaust on his truck. 20 years later, I have the truck, and was able to remove the downpipe bolts without a fight.

Comment: Really something like anti-seize is the only answer. Any actual coating will add material to a thread - especially something readily available to consumers like paint. That material will either make assembly/removal difficult, scrape off during or both.