# Thread on bolt - what happened?

Tags: stuck-bolt, stripped-thread

This is a follow-up question to [Seized nut & bolt - difficult to access](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27319/seized-nut-bolt-difficult-to-access)

What happened - or what did I do wrong - for this bolt to lose its thread in this way?

Is it simply doing it up too tightly? Is that all it is?

[image: Bolt with worn thread]

Comment: Exactly what I had envisioned happened.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks to me like it has been over-tightened, beyond the point of failure of the bolt.

Comment: I would completely agree. Looks like the bolt, while pretty was probably a cheap grade 1 bolt which couldn't handle any kind of torque, might have been the nut, or probably a combination of the two.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that.  Another proud moment.